# Сейчас ваш голос блокирован до тех пор, пока вопрос не будет отредактирован

Tags: обсуждение

Почему спустя некоторое время нельзя отменить голос против? По невнимательности поставил минус, а потом опомнился, захотел отменить а он мне сообщение высвечивает:

> Последний раз вы голосовали за этот ответ 5 минут назад. Сейчас ваш
>   голос блокирован до тех пор, пока вопрос не будет отредактирован.

Необходимо внести правку в ответ, чтобы можно было отменить голос против? А иначе никак нельзя?

Comment: это вот как раз для того чтобы думали при голосовании :-)

Comment: @Grundy, а как же быть с теми, у кого рука дрогнула? Ну, или сгоряча поставили голос, а после того, как вник, нельзя передумать :(

Comment: Ну так после редактирования - можно же

Comment: @Grundy, можно. Но вот только проблема в том, что редактировать практически нечего :) Вопрос именно в том, чтобы не внося правку - проголосовать

Comment: _Вопрос именно в том, чтобы не внося правку - проголосовать_ - на этот вопрос отвечает сообщение в вопросе

Comment: @Grundy, *Последний раз вы голосовали за этот ответ 5 минут назад. Сейчас ваш голос блокирован до тех пор, пока вопрос не будет отредактирован.* - вот это? :)

Comment: да, именно это.

Comment: @Grundy, эх... :)

Comment: Вроде как озвучивался ранее такой вариант: внести правку; отозвать голос; отозвать правку. Все довольны. Почти :)

Comment: @alexolut, тут ключевое слово ***почти*** :) как быть с сообщением, которое не отредактировать...хотя, может быть сообщение низкого качества и заслуживает минус

Comment: @DenisBubnov не отредактировать по причине чего?

Comment: @alexolut, в ответе просто две строки кода. И больше ничего.

Comment: @DenisBubnov разве это мешает выполнить упомянутые мной действия?

Comment: @alexolut, у меня рейтинг не позволяет сделать правку без подтверждения. Я сделал правку, добавил описание и ссылку на MSDN, но правку отклонили.

Comment: @DenisBubnov дайте, плиз, ссылку на тему.

Comment: @alexolut, вот [FileInfo](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/559745/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0-fileinfo)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44532/discussion-between-denis-bubnov-and-alexolut).