# Отзыв голоса против, уточнение справки по этому

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, справка, голоса-против, голосование

Нечаянно поставил голос против, но при попытке отозвать его через некоторое время ничего не получилось.
В поиске ответа наткнулся на [этот](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3590/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%88-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD) вопрос.

Может стоит изменить такое поведение?

Вариант с намеренной правкой довольно "костыльный", тем более когда недостаточно репутации для её внесения.
Как вариант, дать 10-15 минут на возможность отзыва голоса и только после этого срока блокировать его и уменьшать репутацию.

**UPD:**
Qwertiy объяснил, что можно отменить в течение 5 минут, но в справке нет упоминания об этой механике, точнее есть, но слишком расплывчатое:
"Вы сможете отменить свой голос... через некоторое время..."

Может стоит подробнее описать это?

Comment: Эм.. Почему 5 минут - мало, а 10-15 - нормально?

Comment: @Qwertiy Да? Просто как только я нажал отменить голос, мне написали, что я голосовал 5 минут назад. Видимо, немного не успел :)

Comment: Может тогда добавить в справку? Не нашёл [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) упоминания об этом.

Comment: Так это к любым голосам относится.

Comment: @Qwertiy "Вы сможете отменить свой голос... через некоторое время...". Это всё, что есть в справке об этом. Если я не прав, подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно об этом почитать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Конкретное время не прописано в справке, т.к. не было желания привязывать текст в справке к этому значению. Фактически временной интервал менялся в процессе развития Stack Exchange, о чём есть подтверждающие сообщения на MSE:

- [... the vote lock in period is less than 5 minutes. Significantly less.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/34324/339911)
- [I am relaxing the vote undo window to 5 minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/38759/339911)

Достаточно знать, что этот временной интервал относительно мал, а не полагаться на 2, 5, 10 или ещё какое-то другое количество минут. Вполне может быть, что интервал изменится ещё когда-нибудь. В качестве альтернативы, можно было бы прокидывать переменную с конкретным количеством минут в справку, но вряд ли этим будут заморачиваться. К тому же справка переводится несколько иначе, чем весь остальной интерфейс сайта, который доступен нынче через https://ru.traducir.win.

---

Кстати, стоит обратить внимание, что на странице [справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) ruSO текст:

> Нажав на ту же кнопку еще раз, вы сможете отменить свой голос, **но не сразу, а через некоторое время**, поэтому подумайте, прежде чем нажать на нее.

имеет некорректный перевод. Сравните с [оригиналом](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down):

> You can undo your votes by clicking the same vote button, **but only within a small time limit**, so be careful with those clicks.

Следовало бы перевести хотя бы как:

> ... отменить свой голос, **но лишь в течение короткого промежутка времени**, поэтому ...

Comment: «... five minute window ...» прописано в [справочном посте на Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/151960)

Comment: @defaultlocale пост - это пост, а справка - самостоятельные страницы, с ограниченным доступом на редактирование.

Comment: Это да, но Community  FAQ имеет (полу-)официцальный статус. Да и лимит уже больше девяти лет не менялся.